# Entrez.esummary ('gene' db): how to retrieve uid from DictElement?

Tags: biopython

I'm trying to retrieve and save gene summaries from NCBI Entrez Gene database, and would like to keep the uid too, but, though it's there, I can't find the right way to retrieve it from the results. See below (NB: obviously not my valid email address used here):

```
from Bio import Entrez
Entrez.email = "bogus@bogus.com"
handle = Entrez.esummary(db="gene", id="79001")
record = Entrez.read(handle)
handle.close()
for k in record["DocumentSummarySet"]['DocumentSummary'][0].keys():
    print k
```

These are the keys:

> Status, NomenclatureSymbol, OtherDesignations, Mim, Name, NomenclatureName, CurrentID, GenomicInfo, OtherAliases, Summary, GeneWeight, GeneticSource, MapLocation, ChrSort, ChrStart, LocationHist, Organism, NomenclatureStatus, Chromosome, Description

But if you look at the element itself `(record["DocumentSummarySet"]['DocumentSummary'][0])`, you will notice `attributes={u'uid': u'79001'}` at the end:

```
DictElement(
    {u'Status': '0',
     u'NomenclatureSymbol': 'VKORC1',
     u'OtherDesignations': 'phylloquinone epoxide reductase',
     u'Mim': ['608547'],
     u'Name': 'VKORC1',
     u'NomenclatureName': 'vitamin K epoxide reductase complex subunit 1',
     u'CurrentID': '0',
     u'GenomicInfo': [
         {u'ChrAccVer': 'NC_000016.10',
          u'ChrLoc': '16',
          u'ExonCount': '4',
          u'ChrStop': '31090841',
          u'ChrStart': '31094998'}],
     u'OtherAliases': 'EDTP308, MST134, MST576, VKCFD2, VKOR',
     u'Summary': 'This gene [...] variants. [provided by RefSeq, Aug 2015]',
     u'GeneWeight': '46017',
     u'GeneticSource': 'genomic',
     u'MapLocation': '16p11.2',
     u'ChrSort': '16',
     u'ChrStart': '31090841',
     u'LocationHist': [
        {u'AssemblyAccVer': 'GCF_000001405.33',
         u'ChrAccVer': 'NC_000016.10',
         u'AnnotationRelease': '108',
         u'ChrStop': '31090841',
         u'ChrStart': '31094998'}],
     u'Organism': {
         u'CommonName': 'human',
         u'ScientificName': 'Homo sapiens',
         u'TaxID': '9606'},
     u'NomenclatureStatus': 'Official',
     u'Chromosome': '16',
     u'Description': 'vitamin K epoxide reductase complex subunit 1'},
     attributes={u'uid': u'79001'})
```

but 'attributes' is not one of the keys. I am yet to find a way to access the uid kept in attributes. Would anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`attributes` is just an attribute of the DictElement, and you can access it with the standard dot:

```
record["DocumentSummarySet"]['DocumentSummary'][0].attributes
```

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you so much, it was driving me mad; I didn't know DictElements had attributes. Thanks again.

Comment: And thanks for the editing, I'll know how to do things properly next time.

Comment: @SBourgeois, I had to take a peek at the code to find it. https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/Entrez/Parser.py#L96